# How to filter GraphQL query result by joined table column (field)

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

I am trying to filter GraphQL query result by joined table column (field).
Relationship between tables is Many-to-Many (with bridge table of course) and I want to filter Advertisements by the Cities related to them.

I am using C#, .NET 6.0 and EF Core with HotChocolate NuGet package for GraphQL. Just a reminder, filtering by main table columns works just fine. Here is how my Query class looks like:
[image]

And here are the queries I tried:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are them typed:

```
{
  advertisements(where: { and: [{ type: { eq: SERVICE } }, {or: [{cities.name: { {eq:"London"} }}]}] }) {
    title
    id
    owner {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
    description
    rateType
    price
    categories {
      name
    }
    cities {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
{
  advertisements(where: { and: [{ type: { eq: SERVICE } }, {or: [{cities: {name: {eq:"London"}} }]}] }) {
    title
    id
    owner {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
    description
    rateType
    price
    categories {
      name
    }
    cities {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
{
  advertisements(where: { type: { eq: SERVICE } }) {
    title
    id
    owner {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
    description
    rateType
    price
    categories {
      name
    }
    cities(where: {name: {eq: "London"}}) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter statements has to be in "advertisements"

```
advertisements(where:{ type: { eq: SERVICE }} cities: {name: {eq: "London"}})
```

Also, in your Query class you can remove the include statements and instead use [UseProjection]

```
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
public IQueryable<Advertisement> GetAdvertisements([Service] HomyDbContext context) => context.Advertisement;
```